# Does CPU bottleneck and pci-e bandwidth matter when it comes to training and running keras/tf models?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, performance, pci-express, nvme

I have an old Intel NUC (i7-6770HQ) with two m2 slots and connected a 2070 Super using one of these nvme to pcie adapters:

[image]

they are also commonly used for bitcoin mining. I have observed that bench-marking games with this setup results in significantly degraded performance compared to youtube desktop bench marks with the same cards (which is to be expected) because of the slow CPU and the slower pci-e connection. So I was wondering, is this something I have to worry about when it comes to machine learning with tensor-flow or keras? I have no way of benchmarking a desktop setup so I can't be 100% sure. I am planning of perhaps getting a more powerful GPU and I wanted to ensure the setup is technically sound before I do.